# In Android Studio how can I see what the type of an intermediate value of a chain of function calls is?

Tags: android-studio

I want to know what the type of an intermediate value in a chain is. For example, in this chain I want to know what the value is where I've commented `// what is this?`. That is, what is the value of the thing on which `subscribe()` is called?

```
        searchTextObservable
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext { showProgress() }
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map { cheeseSearchEngine.search(it) }
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // what is this?
                .subscribe {
                    hideProgress()
                    showResult(it)
                }
```

EDIT: I'd like to know how to figure this out in general, rather than just for this example

Comment: ObserveOn method signoature : Observable<T> observeOn(Scheduler scheduler) so the return type is an Observable.

Comment: I want to know in general how to figure this out, rather than just for this example